# Android Paralloid and ImageView onClick

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface, android-framelayout

I'm currently trying to implement `Paralloid` by chrisjenx for Android. It uses a `FrameLayout` that hosts two different `layout`s that take up the entire screen size. I need to perform an event during an `ImageView`'s `onClick()`. The `ImageView` is located in the first `layout`.

For example:

```
<Frame Layout>
<Relative Layout>
   <ImageView/>     
   <!-- Need this guys onclick, nothing outputted though. -->
</Relative Layout>
<chris.jenx.paralloid/>
</Frame Layout>
```

I've even gone as far as making sure Relative Layout and Image View both have clickable="true" and focusable="true". No Luck.

Comment: What stops you adding `android:onClick="yourMethod"` to the ImageView?

Comment: @John Shelly: Facing same issue here. Did you solve this?

Comment: @Ravi I have not yet. Its still not registering the clicks. I currently have placed my imageview directly above everything else in the framelayout so its always viewable and clickable for now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the Image clickable property to true?

```
android:clickable="true";
```

Comment: Notice in my question I said I have set both of them to true. So yes.